# Question and Answer with Fixed Timer and grab the time when page redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, timer

I have a small project that involves timer, automatic page redirect and database submission.
I am new to js so iam just doing what i know and what i found on the interent.

**In Summary**
I have qna (10 to 20 questions or more) test that require to work with the timer.

[image]

**Manual submission**
Once the user completed (all or partial) the answers they click the submit button and all the values are submitted to the database with the current timer position.
**Timer runs out**
If the timer runs out a popup window appears with a submit button and click that will submit the current form and redirects to the next page with the entered values.

**Are the Questions are fixed?**
The questions are automatially generated and saved to the database. The questions are take from the Database and displayed to the user.

**Basic form**

```
<form action="submitted.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    <label for="q1">QUESTION-1-FROM-DATABASE</label>
    <input type="text" name="ans_1">

    <label for="q1">QUESTION-2-FROM-DATABASE</label>
    <input type="text" name="ans_2">

    <!-- more -->

    <button type="submit" id="formSubmit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

---

**Timer jquery Plugin**
I am using the Simple.Timer plugin from Csouza (https://csouza.me/jQuery-Simple-Timer/). The timer feature is simple and i was able to redirect

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timer').startTimer({
        onComplete: function(){
            var msg = confirm("Time runs out!");
            if( msg == true ) {
                $("#myForm").submit();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is how can i grab the current time (the time it was redirected). 
i also want to save that to the database.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current system time at any point in JavaScript by using the [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) function.

Executing this function will return a long number, which represents the number of miliseconds since Jan 1st, 1970. If you want to get more details about the date for free, you can simply use `var x = new Date(Date.now())` where the Date constructor is taking a number of milliseconds since 01/01/1970

Your code therefore may look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timer').startTimer({
        onComplete: function(){
            var msg = confirm("Time runs out!");
            var time = new Date(Date.now())
            // do something with the time variable here
            if( msg == true ) {
                $("#myForm").submit();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I wasn't looking for the current time. I am looking for the current **Timer** position. If the test is 10min and the user clicks submits at 5min 30sec, then that is what i need.

Comment: I see, in that case I would consider setting a variable `elapsed` to the current time during the `startTimer` function, and then subtracting the current time from `elapsed` when the user presses submit. It does not seem like there is an easy way to get the remaining time out of simple timer.

Comment: I found another way after seeing your `Date.now()` . I can grab the current time when the user status the test by visiting the test page and save it to the database, and when the user submits, i'll grab the time again and with time difference i can get what i am looking for.